# Как установить pomodairo на Debian

Tags: linux, debian, install

Есть [сайт](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pomodairo/downloads) с файлами для загрузки, но скачивается файл с расширением `air`. Как установить такое приложение?

P.S. `$ sudo apt-cache search pomodairo` - как и `Менеджер пакетов Synaptic` ничего не находит.

Comment: для установки этого приложения Вам нужен Adobe Air, но оффсайт https://get.adobe.com/ru/air/otherversions/ говорит, что для линукс машин его не завезли. Поэтому, либо виртуалка с виндой (для мака конечно можно,  но...), либо попробовать завести под вайном.

Comment: @KoVadim что называете вайном?

Comment: вайн - это [wine](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wine_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). И похоже оно может быть даже заработает https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5842

Comment: @KoVadim установил wine. И как установить `pomodairo`? Ведь файла на подобие виндовсовского setup.exe в скаченном архиве нет.

Comment: Теперь, нужно уставить adobe air. Ссылку, где его взять, я привел

Comment: @KoVadim скачал Adobeairinstaller.exe, но не могу его запустить через открытие как приложение.